# How to make two dimensional LinkedList in java?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

for example:

```
public static LinkedList<String, Double> ll = new LinkedList<String, Double>;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Be sure to check the preview of a post and ensure it formatted the way you expect.  Everything between `<>` disappears unless inside a code section.

Comment: I would interpret "two dimensional list" as a `LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>`, but seeing as you want to use different types you probably want a `Map` instead (which is also one dimensional, by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your question, I think (not 100% sure) you are looking for 
`java.util.LinkedHashMap<K, V>`

in your case, it would be `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>`

from java doc:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries.

if you do want to get element by `list.get(5)`, you could :

```
LinkedList<Entry<String, Double>>
```

so you can get Entry element by `Entry entry = list.get(5)`, then `entry.getKey()` gives you the STring, and `entry.getValue()` gives you the Double.

Comment: The thing is can get items by index? That's why I'm looking for a list not a hash.

Comment: +1  Good overall idea.  Note that LinkedList is slow at accessing by index, so if OP really wants that I'd suggest an ArrayList (as in my post)

Comment: @user949300 I agree array list wins in randomly access. however OP mentioned two things, 1, linkedList, 2 accessing by index. He knows the requirement best. maybe only a couple of times accessing by idx, but million times insert/remove? who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Reading all your comments, I suggest you do something like this:

```
public class StringAndDouble {
    private String str;
    private double dbl;
    // add constructor
    // add getters, setters and other methods as needed.
    // override equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Now you can use:

```
List<StringAndDouble> list = new LinkedList<>(); // or
List<StringAndDouble> list = new ArrayList<>();  // better in most cases
```

Now you can access your objects by index.

This answer creates a new class, to fit your needs. The class has two fields, one `String`, one `double`. This doesn't make the class two dimensional. I think you have a misunderstanding there. When there are `n` dimensions, you need `n` indexes to access an element. You were talking of accessing by index, so I assume you're looking for a one dimensional list holding the objects, that have more than one field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

Comment: I saw String, but where is the double ? :) I didn't understand what OP is asking for, did you?

Answer (score 0):

Since OP in a comment to @Kent says he wants to be able to get items by index...

Note that a `LinkedList` (and `LinkedHashMap`) are *inefficient* at that.  He may prefer an `ArrayList`.  So I would suggest that his "2D" implementation be a

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Double>>
```

which will efficiently support a get by index.

As for the normal `get(String key)`, you'd have to do a linear search of all the entries, which would be inefficient.

So, you have a decision: which way of accessing (by a key or by an index) is more important?

Comment: Index is more important, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Linked Lists within eachother...
For Example:

```
public LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> twoDimLinkedList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Then:

```
////////////////


int value = twoDimLinkedList.get(3).get(4);

/////////////////
```

or (If you were planning on using it for iterative purposes):

```
/////////////////

for (int i = 0; i < twoDimLinkedList.size(); i++) {
    LinkedList<Integer> twoDimLinkedListRow = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int m = 0; m < twoDimLinkedList.get(i).size(); m++) {
        twoDimLinkedListRow.add(value);
    }
    twoDimLinkedList.add(twoDimLinkedListRow);
}
////////////////
```