# How to change the node in the built-in java LinkedList class to add a right and down pointer?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have started to use Java. I want to use the built-in Java LinkedList class with my custom node class (my node class will contain fields: data, down pointer, right pointer). Is it possible to do so?

Here is my node class:

```
public class Node {
int data;
Node rt;
Node dw;

//constructor
public Node(int dataValue) {
    rt=null;
    dw=null;
    data=dataValue;
}
//methods:
public int getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(int dataValue) {
    data = dataValue;
}

public void setrt(Node nextVal) {
    rt=nextVal;
}

public void setdw(Node nextVal) {
    dw=nextVal;
}

public Node getrt() {
    return rt;
}

public Node getdw() {
    return dw;
}
```

I created the following instance:

LinkedList h = new LinkedList<>();

I want to implement a 2D linked list using the built-in linked list class in java. To be able to do this i want to implement my custom node.

Comment: i highly suggest to also add your motivation, why do you want to do this? if you like to use a node, to support some kind of own class implemenation or something, you should definitely start reading on generics. because you can provide any type you like to the linkedlist. - but it is hard to grasp what you want to achieve, by providing this.

Comment: I want to implement a 2D linked list using the built-in linked list class in java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573190/how-to-make-two-dimensional-linkedlist-in-java#

Comment: This uses linked list of linked lists but i want to use my own custom node. Can it be done?

Comment: Okay thanks @OleV.V.

Answer (score 1):

No, the node class of `LinkedList` is private, not exposed, you cannot access it. Except probably through some reflection hack.

And even if you could access the node class, you probably could not replace it with your own class. The `LinkedList` class is hardcoded to use its own node class.

If you really insisted, you could take the source code of the `LinkedList` class and modify it to use your node class. Please check if there are any license problems with such an approach before you do it, though. Also my gut feeling is that it’s not worth the trouble compared to writing your custom linked list class from scratch.

Java’s `LinkedList` is a doubly linked list, so each node has previous and next pointers and reference to data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a LinkedList of your own for this implementation.
But it looks like there are some basic things which you are doing wrong:

- First, as per your implementation, you will be better off with Graph,
  because what you are seeking is graph data structure, with each
  vertex having four edges.
- Second, you should not modify the existing data structures/collection
  API provided by Java. If you really want to use different
  data-structure, then create it and use it.
- And the third and the most important thing to consider is that you
  should always try to use the most efficient data-structures to solve a
  problem. For example, you can create a 2-D Linkedlist, but ask
  yourself, whether is it the most efficient one to store 2-D data? It
  might happen that you could have used a matrix or a graph for storing the data.
- Also, whenever you create or use a datastructure, consider whether
  your application is read/write heavy, based on that you can optimize
  storing and fetching of data.

But, it looks like you have just started, and so I would suggest just to go through basic data-structure books or online resources first.

You can also go through below URL which has similar requirement.

[custom node class with java's linkedlist class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360545/custom-node-class-with-javas-linkedlist-class?rq=1)